# My device is not shown in Apple Watch (Series 4) Bluetooth setting list

Tags: swift, bluetooth, watchkit, core-bluetooth, apple-watch

I want to connect my Bluetooth (BT) Device to my apple watch but it is not shown in bluetooth setting. In iPhone its shown and connecte as well.

In the same iWatch AirPod is connecting properly.
So i want to know the reason and solotion of this problem.

Why all bluetooth device is not shown in iWatch Bluetooth Setting.

My iOS and iWatch is updated. I already reset my iWatch Network Setting and unpare my iWatch with iPhone and pair it again.

Comment: What sort of device is it?  What Bluetooth profile does it use?

Comment: @Paulw11 It is a bluetooth device (combination of --- mic, headset, fan, BT+BLE) which uses Bluetooth classic 4.2 and profile is HFP.

Comment: @Paulw11... again need help :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759031/how-to-stop-announcing-of-siri-shortcuts-parameters-over-headsets-ios-13